# How to prevent QuickTime from showing cursor when playing subtitles?

Tags: macos, quicktime, cursor

I use QuickTime quite a lot for playing mp4 videos with embeed .str subtitles. The only really annoying issue is that the cursor shows up back randomly when a subtitle appears on screen. Some facts about what I'm experiencing:

- It only happens with QuickTime and only when the video has active subtitles. No problems in iTunes, nor in video preview from Finder, neither in VLC or the likes. Videos with no subtitles don't have problems with the cursor.
- When placing the cursor in one corner of the screen the cursor appears back in any other random position of the screen.
- I've been experiencing that for as long as I remember with yosemite and even after re-installing the OSX from scratch.

Has anyone experienced the same? Why is it happening? Any way to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the issue has been solved on the latest OS X El Capitan